# Add extended properties into message which saved in draft folder using EWS XML request

Tags: xml, outlook, exchangewebservices

I need write Outlook App and I need to add some information into extended properties. I use Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync() in my JS code to save message into the draft folder.
Then I generate EWS XML request to get ChangeKey of saved draft by Id recieved in item.saveAsync() callback.
And now I'm trying to add extended properties by the following XML request:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"      xmlns:t=http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1" />
        <t:TimeZoneContext>
            <t:TimeZoneDefinition Id="Eastern Standard Time" />
        </t:TimeZoneContext>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <m:UpdateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly" ConflictResolution="AutoResolve">
            <m:ItemChanges>
                <t:ItemChange>
                    <t:ItemId Id="AQMkAGYzMmY5ZjQ1LTZiZDAtNGUwMy1hN2I0LThmNWM3NGYyY2VhMABGAAADVxv6DmzCb0aSDWQq9af2cwcAiSvs3uFZHUqIGSh2GUm6AAADAQ8AAACJK+ze4VkdSogZKHYZSboAAAI7ViIAAAA=" ChangeKey="CQAAABYAAACJK+ze4VkdSogZKHYZSboAAAAAO3qD" />
                    <t:Updates>
                        <t:SetItemField>
                            <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertySetId="c11ff724-aa03-4555-9952-8fa248a11c3e" PropertyName="prop1" PropertyType="String" />
                            <t:Message>
                                <t:ExtendedProperty>
                                    <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertySetId="c11ff724-aa03-4555-9952-8fa248a11c3e" PropertyName="prop1" PropertyType="String" />
                                    <t:Value>prop1Value</t:Value>
                                </t:ExtendedProperty>
                            </t:Message>
                        </t:SetItemField>
                        <t:SetItemField>
                            <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertySetId="c11ff724-aa03-4555-9952-8fa248a11c4e" PropertyName="prop2" PropertyType="String" />
                            <t:Message>
                                <t:ExtendedProperty>
                                    <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertySetId="c11ff724-aa03-4555-9952-8fa248a11c4e" PropertyName="prop2" PropertyType="String" />
                                    <t:Value>prop2Value</t:Value>
                                </t:ExtendedProperty>
                            </t:Message>
                        </t:SetItemField>
                        <t:SetItemField>
                            <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertySetId="c11ff724-aa03-4555-9952-8fa248a11c5e" PropertyName="prop3" PropertyType="String" />
                            <t:Message>
                                <t:ExtendedProperty>
                                    <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertySetId="c11ff724-aa03-4555-9952-8fa248a11c5e" PropertyName="prop3" PropertyType="String" />
                                    <t:Value>prop3Value</t:Value>
                                </t:ExtendedProperty>
                            </t:Message>
                        </t:SetItemField>
                        <t:SetItemField>
                            <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertySetId="c11ff724-aa03-4555-9952-8fa248a11c6e" PropertyName="prop4" PropertyType="String" />
                            <t:Message>
                                <t:ExtendedProperty>
                                    <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertySetId="c11ff724-aa03-4555-9952-8fa248a11c6e" PropertyName="prop4" PropertyType="String" />
                                    <t:Value>prop4Value</t:Value>
                                </t:ExtendedProperty>
                            </t:Message>
                        </t:SetItemField>
                    </t:Updates>
                </t:ItemChange>
            </m:ItemChanges>
        </m:UpdateItem>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

but in callback I receive failed status and this error

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

I've used https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633633%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx as a sample.

I need to send message with extended properties by "Send" button clicking.

What should I to do?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably your encoding string.

Exchange Web Services chokes on the double quotes in `"utf-8"`.

Use: `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8`